# Creating a plot of frequency of items in a list in python

Tags: python, list, plot

I am trying to take a list of chars:

```
['a','a','b','c','c']
```

and generate a plot with x-axis as the char and the y axis as how many there are in that list.

Comment: what did you try already? it is easier to help with some starting point.

Answer (score 6):

Use `pandas` and count the occurrences of the letters, then make a bar chart:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas

data = ['a','a','b','c','c']
count = Counter(data)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(count, orient='index')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Lol, i did the same thing now, little different, i was waiting for you :-)

Comment: Sort of. I basically had that exact answer, with kind='hist' and was wondering why it wouldn't work

Comment: Maybe mine is worth an +1?

Comment: There you go, +1'd

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
l = ['a','a','b','c','c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'freq': l})
df.groupby('freq', as_index=False).size().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

`pandas` is a large library, which does a lot of stuff with data, as well as plotting (it's using it from [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) though, so you see `plt.show` (`matplotlib.pyplot.show()`), and here you see an example of how you can use it.